# Can anyone suggest tricks for targeting specific units in a big army?

Tags: starcraft-2

Often the engagement of 2 big armies is just a mass of graphics.  Sometimes though you know something is coming.  Like a Ghost with an EMP, or a High Templar with Psionic Storm, etc.  In these engagements you'd obviously want to do what you can to kill these units before they get a chance to do their damage.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adjusting your video settings;  Different features stand out more or less when you adjust things like texture resolution and effects quality.  A good way to experiment is to open a replay with an engagement similar to what you're describing, watching the engagement; making an adjustment to your settings and watching the engagement again.  Do this until you find a balance you are pleased with.

In my own experience, on my own machine, lowering the effects qualtiy tends to make cloaked units more visible, but at the cost of making  burrowed units less visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift-queue attack orders before the battle starts; is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest lowering your mouse speed. Pros play with very low mouse speeds so that they can click more accurately.

This means that you'll snipe a High Templar instead of the Zealot next to it.